# Failed to create table with SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to create a table with a list of names in it. This outputs:

> "Failed to create table_name"

It was working before, I'm using Netbeans IDE with SQLite 3.7.2. I've also tried executing statements on the database which works fine. But it won't work through the Java code below

```
class DatabaseHelper{    
    public void addToDb(String tbname, List<String> name){
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:D:/names.db";
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url); 
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();){
                stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tbname + "(id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                        + "name text NOT NULL)");

                name.forEach((s) -> {
                    try{
                        stmt.execute("INSERT INTO " + tbname + "(name) VALUES('" + s + "')");
                    }catch(SQLException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                System.out.println("Finished");
            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT : It does works, only takes to refresh it. No actual problems it seems

Comment: failed to create database or table, the error says database_name and in your code you try to create table?

Comment: it was a typo, I'll fix it now

Comment: print all the error please

Comment: use `ex.printStackTrace();` in your catch to print your error

Comment: if there were errors I would put it up. the stmt.execute returns a boolean hence the output "failed to create table_name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create your table with a database name like this :

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS databasename." + tbname + 
               " (id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name text NOT NULL)";
```

If your database already contain schema then create your table with schema name like this :

[image: structure to create a table sqlite]

```
CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [schema_name].table_name (
```

so :

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sch_name." + tbname + 
               " (id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name text NOT NULL)";
```

You can learn more here : [SQLite Create Table](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-create-table/)

## Ooops this is logic

This error is logic it return false all the time, if you try `st.executeUpdate(q)` and your query is success it will return `0` because **CREATE TABLE** does not return any thing for that you get negative result all the time, not like **Insert or Update** it return a result when you execute your statement, so i suggest to change your code to this :

```
boolean created;
try {
    q = "CREATE TABLE ...";
    Statement st = connection.createStatement();

    //you can use
    System.out.println(st.executeUpdate(q));
    //or 
    System.out.println(st.execute(q));

    created = true;
} catch (SQLException e) {
    created = false;
}

//now you can check if your table is created or not
if(created){
    System.out.println("Table created with sucess");
}else{
    System.out.println("Faild to create table");
}
```

Hope this work with you.

Comment: thank you for the informations. The Java code returns a fail to create table, and in the services tab under "table", I couldn't see the table. But when I refresh it, it's there

Comment: so, your solution works? or what did you mean @UnsolvedRubiks

Comment: it does work, but it seems like I need to refresh it through the services tab

Comment: read my edit @UnsolvedRubiks you are correct and you get correct result read my edit so you can understand more

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tbname + ";"+"CREATE TABLE "+ tbname + "(id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                                + "name text NOT NULL)"))
```

or can you give the exception that was raised

Comment: the stmt.execute returns a boolean